# iOS : UIView does not display

Tags: ios, uiview

I customed an UIView

```
@implementation PaiLifePageDetail

@synthesize pageIndex = _pageIndex;

#define MARGINTOTOP 200.0
#define MARGINTOLEFT 20.0
#define WIDTH 120.0
#define HEIGHT 150.0


- (id) initWithDataSource : (NSArray *) dataSource
{
self = [super init];
if (self)
{
    if (dataSource)
    {
        for (PaiLifeCustomImageView *imageView in dataSource)
        {
            //page 1 line 1
            if (_pageIndex == 1)
            {
                if ([imageView.location isEqualToString:@"r11"])
                {
                    imageView.frame = CGRectMake(MARGINTOLEFT, MARGINTOTOP, WIDTH, HEIGHT * 2);
                    [self addSubview:imageView];
                }
                else if ([imageView.location isEqualToString:@"r12"])
                {
                    imageView.frame = CGRectMake(MARGINTOLEFT + WIDTH + 20, MARGINTOTOP, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
                    [self addSubview:imageView];
                }
            }
            //not page 1 line 1
            else
            {
                if ([imageView.location isEqualToString:@"r11"])
                {
                    imageView.frame = CGRectMake(MARGINTOLEFT, MARGINTOTOP, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
                    [self addSubview:imageView];
                }
                else if ([imageView.location isEqualToString:@"r12"])
                {
                    imageView.frame = CGRectMake(MARGINTOLEFT + WIDTH + 20, MARGINTOTOP, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
                    [self addSubview:imageView];
                }
                else if ([imageView.location isEqualToString:@"r13"])
                {
                    imageView.frame = CGRectMake(MARGINTOLEFT + (WIDTH + 20) * 2, MARGINTOTOP, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
                    [self addSubview:imageView];
                }
            }

            // line 2
            if ([imageView.location isEqualToString:@"r21"])
            {
                imageView.frame = CGRectMake(MARGINTOLEFT, MARGINTOTOP + HEIGHT + 20, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
                [self addSubview:imageView];
            }
            else if ([imageView.location isEqualToString:@"r22"])
            {
                imageView.frame = CGRectMake(MARGINTOLEFT + WIDTH + 20, MARGINTOTOP + HEIGHT + 20, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
                [self addSubview:imageView];
            }
            else if ([imageView.location isEqualToString:@"r23"])
            {
                imageView.frame = CGRectMake(MARGINTOLEFT + (WIDTH + 20) * 2, MARGINTOTOP + HEIGHT + 20, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
                [self addSubview:imageView];
            }

            // line 3
            if ([imageView.location isEqualToString:@"r31"])
            {
                imageView.frame = CGRectMake(MARGINTOLEFT, MARGINTOTOP + (HEIGHT + 20) * 2, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
                [self addSubview:imageView];
            }
            else if ([imageView.location isEqualToString:@"r32"])
            {
                imageView.frame = CGRectMake(MARGINTOLEFT + WIDTH + 20, MARGINTOTOP + (HEIGHT + 20) * 2, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
                [self addSubview:imageView];
            }
            else if ([imageView.location isEqualToString:@"r33"])
            {
                imageView.frame = CGRectMake(MARGINTOLEFT + (WIDTH + 20) * 2, MARGINTOTOP + (HEIGHT + 20) * 2, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
                [self addSubview:imageView];
            }

        }
    }
}
[self setNeedsDisplay];
return self;
}
@end
```

And this is my view

```
implementation PaiLifeViewController

@synthesize detail = _detail;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
UIImage *i = [UIImage imageNamed:@"menu_patcode_normal"];
PaiLifeCustomImageView *c1 = [[PaiLifeCustomImageView alloc] initWithImage:i];
c1.location = @"r11";
PaiLifeCustomImageView *c2 = [[PaiLifeCustomImageView alloc] initWithImage:i];
c2.location = @"r12";
PaiLifeCustomImageView *c4 = [[PaiLifeCustomImageView alloc] initWithImage:i];
c4.location = @"r21";
PaiLifeCustomImageView *c5 = [[PaiLifeCustomImageView alloc] initWithImage:i];
c5.location = @"r22";
PaiLifeCustomImageView *c6 = [[PaiLifeCustomImageView alloc] initWithImage:i];
c6.location = @"r23";
PaiLifeCustomImageView *c7 = [[PaiLifeCustomImageView alloc] initWithImage:i];
c7.location = @"r31";
PaiLifeCustomImageView *c8 = [[PaiLifeCustomImageView alloc] initWithImage:i];
c8.location = @"r32";
PaiLifeCustomImageView *c9 = [[PaiLifeCustomImageView alloc] initWithImage:i];
c9.location = @"r33";

NSArray *c = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:c1,c2,c4,c5,c6,c7,c8,c9, nil];

//PaiLifePageDetail *pagec
_detail.pageIndex = 1;
_detail= [[PaiLifePageDetail alloc] initWithDataSource:c];
[_detail awakeFromNib];
}
@end
```

But it does not display, I don't know why ,help me with this. Thank you.

Comment: It seems that you never add your view to your view controller, do you?

Comment: @Matthias I add my view to my view controller in IB.

Comment: Well, according your code your `detail` object is created in `viewDidLoad`, i.e. to late for NIB automatisation. If you want to load a custom view from a NIB, you have to override ` initWithCoder:`, c.f. [Apple's guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/windowsviews/conceptual/viewpg_iphoneos/CreatingViews/CreatingViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH5-SW23).

Answer (score 0):

```
[self.view addSubview:_detail];
```

in viewcontroller viewdidload